# адаптивный UI на WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго времени суток.
Хочу чтобы окно моего приложения. На разных мониторах отображалось одинаково (сохранение пропорций элементов внутри окна).
Для примерна стал баловаться с простым диалоговым окном.
Требования к окну такие:
запускается всегда на весь экран и отображает всего 4 контролла размер которых должен меняться пропорционально в зависимости от разрешения монитора.

```
<Window x:Class="testResolution.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testResolution"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    WindowState="Maximized"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="400" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="SlateGray" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />

    </Style>
</Window.Resources>


<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Name="TicketName"
               Grid.Row="0"
               Margin="10"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Background="White"
               FontSize="60"
               Foreground="Black"
               Padding="5"
               Text="ТЕКСТ 1111"
               TextAlignment="Center" />

    <TextBlock Name="CountPeople"
               Grid.Row="1"
               Margin="10"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Background="White"
               FontSize="60"
               Foreground="Black"
               Padding="5"
               Text="ТЕКСТ 22222"
               TextAlignment="Center" />

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

        <Button Name="BtnOk"
                Content="Принять"
                Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />

        <Button Name="BtnCancel"
                Content="Отменить"
                Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />

    </StackPanel>



</Grid>
```

Подскажите как это сделать?
Заранее всем спасибо!!!

Comment: Что значит пропорционально? На экране 640х480 и 1920х1080 картинка должна быть пропорционально растянута и только? Батоны ваши должны занимать треть высоты или достаточно того, что они будут снизу, занимая 400х100 каждый, как у вас забито в стиле?

Comment: Кнопки просто снизу. ну и чтобы визуально пропорционально изменилась каринка на другом разрешении.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы кнопки не менялись от размеров, а текст - менялся, стоит переделать разметку вот так:

```
  <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
```

`Auto` - режим минимально необходимый для отображения. `*` - жадный режим отображения, заберёт, что отдадут.

Comment: я вот думаю может еще в стилях кнопки не задавать явно ширину и высоту. а задать только минимальные значения ширины и высоты?

Comment: @Aldmi на ваше усмотрение. Лучше вживую проверять, как оно себя поведет на разных настройках разных контролов.

Answer (score 0):

Если сделать так

```
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

то на маленьком разрещении кнопки опять будт большие а все остальное сожмется пропорционально